# How do I make an Auto Clicker Macro in LUA script inside Logitech ghub?

Tags: lua, macros, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I am trying to make an auto clicker that repeats while holding the mouse 5 button on my g703. It should keep sending the PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1) function until I am no longer holding down the mouse 5 button.
This is currently my code:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 5 then
      repeat
         Sleep(15)
         PressAndReleaseMouseButton(1)
         Sleep(15)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5) 
   end
end
```

However this only sends one click when I press the mouse 5 button when I want it to be repeatedly sending clicks while the mouse 5 is held down. What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Probably you have changed default binding ("Forward") of physical button #5.  You should go to "Assignments" mouse page in GHUB, click on the white circle corresponding to MB#5 and select "USE DEFAULT" from drop-down list.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("capslock")then
if  IsMouseButtonPressed(5)then
   repeat
   MoveMouseRelative(0,4)
   PressMouseButton(1)
   Sleep(1,2)
   ReleaseMouseButton(1)
   until not IsMouseButtonPressed(5)
end
end
end
```